# A class which implemements `IGeneratable` has to provide a `IGeneratorConstructor<T>` where `T`is the class which implements `IGeneratable`

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, type-inference

I want to achieve that a class which implemements `IGeneratable` has to provide a `IGeneratorConstructor<T>` where `T`is the class which implements `IGeneratable`.

Is that possible in TypeScript (3.8.3, specifically)? If so, how?

```js
export class Example implements IGeneratable {
    public generator = ExampleGenerator;
}

export class ExampleGenerator implements IGenerator<Example> {
    private _component: Example;

    constructor(context: GeneratorContext<Example>) {
        this._component = context.component;
    }

    getId(): string {
        return 'myID';
    }

    build(): void {
        // build something with the information of this.component
    }
}
```

These are my current types:

```js
export interface IGeneratable {
    generator: IGeneratorConstructor<any>; // need help here
}

export interface GeneratorContext<TComponent extends IGeneratable> {
    scene: Scene;
    component: TComponent;
}

export interface IGenerator<TComponent extends IGeneratable> {
    getId(): string;

    build(): void;
}

export interface IGeneratorConstructor<TComponent extends IGeneratable> {
    new (context: GeneratorContext<TComponent>): IGenerator<TComponent>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make the `IGeneratable` type generic:

```js
export interface IGeneratable<TComponent extends IGeneratable<TComponent>> {
    generator: IGeneratorConstructor<TComponent>; // need help here
}

export interface GeneratorContext<TComponent extends IGeneratable<TComponent>> {
    scene: Scene;
    component: TComponent;
}

export interface IGenerator<TComponent extends IGeneratable<TComponent>> {
    getId(): string;

    build(): void;
}

export interface IGeneratorConstructor<TComponent extends IGeneratable<TComponent>> {
    new (context: GeneratorContext<TComponent>): IGenerator<TComponent>;
}
```

This gives error as expected:

```
export class Example2 implements IGeneratable<Example2> {
    // no generator defined
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Didn't saw this possibility.